# Understanding of Hypothesis testing and further actions

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I know Hypothesis Testing is a statistical test, for a sample of data stands true for the entire population or not. That is, if a random sample's mean is same as that of the population mean. Here, we try to accept or reject NULL hypothesis by various tests like Z-Test/ T-Test / ANOVA / Chi-Square Test.

1. What we do after accepting or rejecting NULL hypothesis?
2. Do we exclude/include that sample from further process if we are building a machine learning model?
3. What are the significance of accepting NULL Hypothesis?
4. What are the significance of accepting Alternate Hypothesis?
5. Or is there any other insights we make with these tests?
6. Which test is good for the sample, to be considered in a machine learning for model building?

I would like to know these in the perspective of machine learning for model building.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my thoughts to your questions from the perspective of a Biologist:

What comes after rejecting your null-hypothesis is that you are happy and able to mark that star (*) in your plot, that everyone wants to see in order to be able to publish the result. Sarcasm: A star on the plot means that whichever hypothesis you can read in the title of the plot, is obviously true.

Jokes aside, not being able to reject the null-hypothesis means that your result could **also** be explained by defined randomness. On the other side, being able to reject the null-hypothesis means that your controlled stochastic randomness cannot explain your result. What I mean with "controlled stochastic randomness", a term I just invented, is a form of randomness that you are aware of and you measured and analyzed in a controlled manner. For example you measure the length of an object 100 times and your device reports a slightly different number each measurement. If you now accidentally used another measurement device and got a different result, then this would not be part of your defined randomness and you can forget all math done by the test, that assumes something else.

So far to what the test really says, now to your question what should come after rejecting the null-hypothesis:

To even start to draw meaningful conclusions from the statement "the difference in mean cannot be explained by randomness alone", you have to think of all possible other explanations, biases or accidents that could have caused the result and try to show with further experiments that only your hypothesis can explain that all. Many times, scientists forget or ignore simple explanations for their results in favor of an outlandish hypothesis that they want to publish. In theory you can never fully prove a causal relationship, and surely not with a single T-test.